# I am getting maximum call stack exceed error while modifying push method

Tags: javascript

I am trying to modify pus method using Array.prototype with the following

```js
Array.prototype.push = function (ele) {
  this.length++;
  this[this.length - 1] = ele;
  console.log(ele);
};

const arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr.push(5);
console.log(arr);
```

I am getting maximum call stack exceeded error but after removing console.log(arr), it is working fine

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: @link2name i was asked this in an interview

Comment: Do you really wanna work there after such question?

Comment: If in an interview, they are either trying to get you to say "I would not change the Array prototype, that would be a bad idea." instead of actually writing the code, or they are giving you signals that you should avoid that particular position.

Comment: @Chase thanks for advice I will remember that. I told him that i would not change the prototype, just out of curiosity i was trying if it is possible or not

Comment: Do not modify existing push, You could instead write a new method like Array.prototype.mypush

Comment: There are other issues with this push method. It should take multiple arguments, not just a single element `ele`. So, something like `function (...elements) { }` to collect all inputs. And the `push` method should return the length of the array. And you don't need to increment the length manually. Just set each element to: `this[this.length]` and the length will automatically update

Answer (score 0):

In node, the `console` use `Array.prototype.push` internally. And I believe browser may behave a similar way. But the behavior of console is dependent on vendor, so just treat it as an example.

See :(under node 16)

```
(node:76599) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Array.push (REPL5:4:11)
    at formatRaw (internal/util/inspect.js:979:12)
    at formatValue (internal/util/inspect.js:774:10)
    at inspect (internal/util/inspect.js:319:10)
    at formatWithOptionsInternal (internal/util/inspect.js:1979:40)
    at formatWithOptions (internal/util/inspect.js:1861:10)
    at console.value (internal/console/constructor.js:327:14)
    at console.log (internal/console/constructor.js:363:61)
    at Array.push (REPL5:4:11)
    at formatRaw (internal/util/inspect.js:979:12)
```

Comment: Nothing in OPs question mentions `node`